# How to tell Vimeo which video size to deliver responsive

Tags: html, responsive-design, vimeo-player

It's pretty easy to embed Vimeo's iframe in a responsive manner, so that the player changes in size.

BUT: **Does Vimeo actually deliver the video in a correct size then?**

First I assumed wrongly that they would check for bandwidth and progressively enhance quality or resolution, but [Adaptive Streaming apparently is a thing for the future](https://vimeo.com/blog/post/adaptive-streaming-and-4k-coming-soon-for-your-vid).

Do they at least downscale videos?

F.e. when uploading a video in 3000 px width and embedding it on a site in the responsive player, the video always seems to have a much lower resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For adaptive streaming plays: yes. We set the maximum allowed resolution based on the size of the player and the device pixel ratio and it will adjust if the player size changes.

For progressive plays, the player defaults to SD. If the viewer clicks on the HD button, we will set their preference and the player will always use their preferred resolution when available. Plus and PRO members have an option to set the default resolution to HD, but that setting only matters for viewers without a preference.

Comment: You may want to make it clearer that you're actually an authority in this topic :)

Comment: Thx Brad. Is the _dppx_ taken into account as well with adaptive streaming?

Comment: Brad, for progressive plays, just to clarify: When embedding a Plus-member's video that has the HD-Setting active, even a player sized with 300 px width will load a video in 1920 px width?

Comment: Yes, the device pixel ratio is taken into account. So if you have an embed at 640x360 and are watching on a retina screen (2x) you will get the 1280x720 video.

Comment: If it's a Plus member's video with the "Default to HD" option turned on, we will show 720p if the user hasn't explicitly selected a quality before. As soon as they do, we will show the one they chose (or the closest one available).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can think of is to adjust your webpage and embed the video in the optimum size for playback. Your guests will assume that video quality/size may change based on the device they are using to view. I tend to go with embedding video at a size that works well on a laptop, so that the video is a bit small but plays well on a pc, a bit large but still loads on a tablet.

Comment: When you refer to _size_, you're taking about the presented size (CSS), right? Not the actual size of the delivered video file(s), or the size used in the iframe-parameters. So your answer is more a UX consideration, I guess?